# How to make a Console application work from an empty project in Xamarin studio

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin-studio

I've created a simple "hello world" application, starting from an Empty Project. The code just prints a hello world

```
public class Test_Class {
    public static void Main() {
        System.Console.WriteLine ("hello, world");
    }
}
```

But no console window pops up when I run the application. How do I make the console show?

Comment: If you run your application from the console does it display anything? Or is it that nothing is displayed in Xamarin Studio when you run the application? If you are not seeing anything in the Application Output window in Xamarin Studio you could try using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test empty project."); instead to see if that displays anything.

Comment: Yeah I mean when I run that code out of empty project I expect the same results I get when I run it out of a console application template. I tried using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Test empty project.")  and this time it did print the string but it was on the bottom of the screen in Application output instead of a command prompt thing like I wanted.

Comment: OK now I understand :) To get the console window to open in your project when you debug the application you need to change your project options. In the Solution pad, right click your project, select Options. Then inside the Run category select General. Then make sure Run on external console is ticked.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the "Run on external console" checkbox from `Project Options -> Run -> General`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Xamarin Studio
2. There is a link on left upper corner for "New Solution", click on it
3. A new windows is open for "choose a template for your new project"
4. From left side menu other->.NET
5. give project name, solution name, and create project
6. Left panel in solution->project_name->add

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Studio, create a console application,

Make sure in the left tree view you select C# node, and in the middle list you should be able to see the console application template.

You cannot use other template yet, as they are for other purposes.

There is a tutorial online, which can help you get started,

http://books.cs.luc.edu/introcs-csharp/

(Updated: Xamarin has updated the look and feel of Xamarin Studio in 5.9, so you need to get used to the new wizards and so on.)

Comment: @Griffin, an IDE with active development like Xamarin Studio can change significantly. I personally think it is impossible for a StackOverflow answer to always be up-to-date. The viewers should be able to adapt to the newer IDE releases, as the core steps are still the same.

Comment: it's very possible. I promise.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I first started using Xamarin Studio and after a lot of search, I found that the example code you provided and witch comes with the creation of the solution, will give an error on this line

```
Console.WriteLine ("Test empty project.");
```

because of some sort conflict with the namespaces.
You have to use

```
System.Console.WriteLine ("Test empty project.");
```

and than press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>